# Auth0 - Missing isAuthenticated; and authenticate()

Tags: angularjs, auth0

I have an angular 1.6 application - i am trying to migrate an old version of auth0 v9 lock to v11.

```
property: auth.IsAuthenticated
function: auth.authenticate();
```

From what i can tell both the above property and function have been deprecated in the new version, but i was not able to find a replacement within the new lock v11 (lock) api or the migration guide.

Can someone help me understand what these functions did(i have an idea) and help me with determining what to replace them with.

thanks.

Comment: are you still having trouble with this? is this the document you looked at for migration and couldn't find the answer to your question? https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/migration-angularjs-v9

Comment: @kimcodes i resolved it.

Comment: Great! Feel free to share your solution as the answer and mark it as solved. Another user may have a similar issue and it could help them.